Google Form onFormSubmit TypeError, But I already used trigger for onFormSubmit
Anyone can help me? My code has an error just like this "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values') onFormSubmit @ Limit Response.gs:2".
The process of my Form is when user select the option on dropdown, when submit it the choice selected is remove from the choices.
This is the code: https://collabedit.com/yk7fr?fbclid=IwZXh0bgNhZW0CMTAAAR2SAYzGAwzY6JEDGbGgVa21JajK1sjaY5qA3LXYoM6tsSeWmfhBXS7NFQM_aem_AbEOQhogV01TkCEAXAk4acTkaIy4dGus3tdFcexHvqO9qKw-m6BqwO7vEU6HJu8MmP-U3gAsyzm3HWhCESxgbhXs

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your code (a minimal, complete and verifiable example, not your whole code), directly in your question, not via a link.
